# How to change the colour of mobile menu items only, with the Bridge WordPress Premium Theme?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, mobile-website

How can I change the colour of my mobile menu items?

Currently, it's blue and I want to change it to another colour. I'm using a premium WordPress theme called "[Bridge - Creative Multipurpose WordPress Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054)"

I can find out any options for changing it. Please help me. It's will be better if I can get a guideline step by step. I would like to attach an image here.
Thank you all in advance.

[mobile menu items colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUpxg.png)

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the mobile menu you have to write media Query and give the colors as per your requirement.

```
@media (max-width:767px){
     //Write the CSS for Mobile Layout.
}
```

Comment: Shrestha, Thank you so much. I'll try this way. I believe it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a `classname` on the parent of the said items.
Say you have an `html` like this:

```
<nav class="my-class-name">
  <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
</nav>
```

You can then target all descendants of the parent with the `classname` you've added and change it's color accordingly.

```
.my-class-name a {
 color: {your-color-value here};
}
```

Since wordpress and its themes' coding standard may vary, if you didn't find the solution to work, you can add an `!important` tag at the end of the `css` property

There are ways on how you can add a custom style rules on your wordpress website. A much more better way is install a `snippet` plugin such as woody snippet and add you custom style declaration by using the plugin.

If you only want to apply the style rule on mobile only, [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) are your friend.

Comment: Jpneey, Thank you so much. I'll try this way. I believe it'll work.